# How to read machine GUID which is present "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography" using WMI class?

Tags: wmi, guid, wmic, regedit

I have this query, that can we read machine GUID which is present **"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography"** using WMI class ? If possible then do tell me.

I tried and search it a lot and found result for "how to read **machine GUID** from registry?".

Above two has created a confusion that is this Machine GUID in registry is same to some UUID or combination of UUID's that can be fetched from WMI or totally independent.
Can you please tell me cause of Machine GUID in registry being "default" and "null" and it's chances of two machines having same Machine GUID.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the MachineGuid from the Registry will be identical if the two machines were clones.

I have had more luck with the UUID since it seems to respond to hardware changes such as when two VMWARE machines are created from the same image.

```
wmic csproduct get UUID
```

See the following for more details.

```
wmic csproduct get name,identifyingnumber,uuid
```